# Google Apps Script returning out of bounds errors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to insert a column on a Google Sheet with 37 columns. All columns have data.
When I execute this line of code

```
enhancedpreSheet.insertColumnAfter(31);
```

I get an error "Those columns are out of bounds". I can't explain why.
I tried to troubleshoot the problem and got even more confused.
When I execute

```
Logger.log("enhancedpreSheet last column:" + enhancedpreSheet.getLastColumn());
Logger.log("enhancedpreSheet max column:" + enhancedpreSheet.getMaxColumns());
```

I get:

```
[21-08-06 20:21:33:572 EDT] enhancedpreSheet last column:37
[21-08-06 20:21:33:572 EDT] enhancedpreSheet max column:26
```

How can getLastColumn() return a higher value than getMaxColumns()?
And why is getMaxColumns() returning 26 instead of 37?

Comment: What happens if you reduce the number of rows by a significant amount?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] including a spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view only having only the elements required to reproduce the error.

Comment: Reducing the number of rows doesn't change the ourcome

Minimal reproducible example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LzPy_ThYSx1vePNnvHV4uINWFeriIhvJNltZ8FcKL0E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have checked with you sheet but both return 37.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` before you inserting the new column.

It looks like SpreadsheepApp just can't keep up to fill all the cells of the table at the time as the new command (to insert new column) is arriving.

Comment: It's not surprising. It's one of less obvious spreadsheet tricks that has little to do with JS. Even quite experienced guy @idfurw didn't guess it out.